# Prevent attaching debugger to external DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, interop

From my C# application I'm integrating with a 3rd-party DLL using interop (`DllImport`). I suspect that DLL is written in C++ or maybe C++/CLI.

That 3rd-party DLL refuses to run in a debugger (when running my application from within Visual Studio, the DLL produces a message box saying it won't run in a debugger).

Is there a Visual Studio setting oder some interop hack which allows me to run my application in debug mode, but without having the debugger attached to the external 3rd-party DLL?

Comment: No.  It is pretty easy for such a DLL to [check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-isdebuggerpresent).  Only hope you have is that it won't detect the managed debugging engine, ensure that the native debugging option is turned off.  Project > Properties > Debug tab.  If that doesn't help then ask the DLL owner for support.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Native debugging is disabled, so I guess I'm out of luck here...

Answer (score 0):

Because the information you provided is limited, I have given several solutions, please try them one by one.

1. Dll project, properties - configuration properties - debugging - set the command to bin\Debug*.exe of the exe project that calls the dll
2. Dll project, properties - configuration properties - debugging - set the debugger type to local only
3. Dll project, properties - configuration properties - general - set the output directory to the bin\Debug directory of the exe project that calls the dll
4. Set a breakpoint in the dll project, and then regenerate the dll project, in order to output the dll to the set directory
5. Exe project, properties - debugging - enable unmanaged code debugging
6. Exe project, set as startup project
7. Tools - Options - Debugging - Remove the check mark in front of (Enable "Only My Code") and use Managed Compatibility Mode at the same time. In the c++ project settings, the debugger type should be set to automatic (not set to native only).